# Vectorised R functions

Tags: r

The `a` and `b` as shown below are the same quantities but are calculated in two different ways in R. They are mostly the same but with several big differences. I could not figure out why that was the case.

```
theta0 <- c(-0.4, 10)

OS.mean <- function(shape, rank, n=100){
  term1 <- factorial(n)/(factorial(rank-1)*factorial(n-rank))
  term2 <- beta(n-rank+1, rank) - beta(n-rank+shape+1, rank)
  term1*term2/shape
}

OS.mean.theta0.100 <- OS.mean(theta0[1], rank=seq(1, 100, by=1))

Bias.MOP <- function(shape, scale, alpha){
  scale*shape*OS.mean.theta0.100[alpha*100]/(1-(1-alpha)^shape) - scale
}

a <- rep(0, 98)
for(i in 2:99){
  a[i-1] <- Bias.MOP(theta0[1], theta0[2], i/100)
}
plot(a)

b <- Bias.MOP(theta0[1], theta0[2], seq(0.02, 0.99, by=0.01))
plot(b)

a-b
```

One other strange thing is as follows.

```
b[13] # -0.8185083
Bias.MOP(theta0[1], theta0[2], 0.14) # -0.03333929
```

They are supposed to be the same. But they clearly are not. Why?

Comment: Check `((2:99)/100) - seq(0.02, 0.99, by=0.01)`.

Comment: @Pascal They are quite close with difference e-17. But you will see some entries  of `a-b` are 0.3. Is that normal? By the way, which method is better?

Comment: @BondedDust Which section?

Comment: Miscellaneous: why aren't these numbers equal

Comment: OP is not commenting on the small differences of order e-16 etc. they are commenting on those few points that are different on order e-1: indices 13, 28, 56, 57.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Yes, exactly. Do you know why, please? Moreover, why are `b[13]` and `Bias.MOP(theta0[1], theta0[2], 0.14)` so different?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Change `alpha*100` to `round(alpha * 100)` and it solves the problem. Answer forthcoming

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, it did. But what went wrong, please? In particular, why are `b[13]` and `Bias.MOP(theta0[1], theta0[2], 0.14)` so different, please? They are indeed the same procedure.

Comment: Odd - `seq(.02, .99, by=.01)[13]*100) - 14` is on the order `e-15`. But `as.integer(seq(...)) - 14` is `-1`. Your index `alpha*100` is evaluating to 14 for `.14/100`, but to 13 for the `seq(...)`.

Comment: @DavidRobinson By the way, what will happen if I write `x[1.01]` where `x` is a vector, but `1.01` is not an integer?

Comment: @20824 you know, you can try all these things out yourself..

Comment: Just to be clear... This was yet another instance of not understanding the faq about numeric values. With the additional bit of knowledge that indices are truncated down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are indexing by a numeric, `alpha*100` in this line:

```
OS.mean.theta0.100[alpha*100]
```

When [floating point error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) causes `seq(0.02, 0.99, by=0.01)` to be even *slightly* less than the corresponding integer in `2:99`, you end up extracting the wrong number from `theta0.100`. For example, see:

```
x <- 1:10
x[5]
# [1] 5
x[6]
# [1] 6
x[5.99999999]
# [1] 5
```

A quick solution is to change `alpha*100` to `round(alpha*100)`, as below, to ensure that you're always selecting by the nearest round number.

```
Bias.MOP <- function(shape, scale, alpha){
  scale*shape*OS.mean.theta0.100[round(alpha*100)]/(1-(1-alpha)^shape) - scale
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But still without modifying my function, why are `b[13]` and `Bias.MOP(theta0[1], theta0[2], 0.14)` so different, please? They are supposed to be correct or wrong together. Right?

Comment: @20824 Because of [floating point error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874867/floating-point-issue-in-r). Try `.14 - seq(0.02, 0.99, by=0.01)[13]`. You would expect it to be 0, but it is not. Thus, `OS.mean.theta0.100[alpha*100]` will be chosen differently between those two alphas.

Comment: Yes. I see. Thanks again. Does other software deal with this kind of things better than R. Such as Python or something else?

Comment: @20824 *No.* Floating point error is [universal](http://floating-point-gui.de/) [across](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) [languages](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx). One of the ways to handle it (besides being aware of it) is not to use the result of floating point calculations directly in indexing, or in equalities

Comment: @20824 For example, you could have organized your function as `scale*shape*OS.mean.theta0.100[alpha]/(1-(1-alpha / 100)^shape) - scale` instead, then pass it `2:99`. That would work perfectly.