# precision of R - sprintf("%.100f",36*0.01)

Tags: r

this may be a newbee question yet i have not found anything on it:

In R when t type

sprintf("%.100f",36*0.01)

i get
0.3599999999999999866773237044981215149164199829101562500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

as a result.

Similarly,

> 100 * 0.011 * 1000000000000000000000000000000000000
>   [1] 109999999999999985480886002800028446

How is this possible?
I´d really welcome your help!

Best 
Chisuz

Comment: [this should answer your question.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6874927/7591607)

Comment: thank you for all answers provided!