# Find row based on its value

Tags: r

I remember coming across this issue in the past but I cannot find the solution anymore.

For a dataframe with the numeric column `a` I want to find the row for which `a = 27.99`. View the dataframe I know that in row 100 this is the case.

So:

```
> df$a[100]
27.99

> df$a[100] == 27.99
FALSE

> which(df$a == 27.99)
integer(0)

> is.numeric(df$a[100])
TRUE
```

I remember it might have to do with machine precision.

Comment: `which(grepl(28, df$a))`

Comment: should not happen with integer data actually. Can you add a reproducible example? Moreover, you can check with `which(sapply(df$a, all.equal, 28) == TRUE)`

Comment: Oh, yes, maybe I should specify, it's not an integer but rather `27.99`. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be an issue with floating points, try:

`which(round(df$a) == 28)`

see: [floating point issue in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874867/floating-point-issue-in-r)
also this has a very thorough explanation: [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)