# how to make very small number to exact zero in r?

Tags: r

Recently, I found something weird thing in my Rstudio. it is as follows:
[image]

It is the output of the following code.

```
 data = iris[,-5]
 scaled_data = scale(data)
 colMeans(scaled_data)
```

I think the result of "colMeans(scaled_data)" is totally zero.
But as you see, It is not a ZERO. 
Is there any solution for this problem? or any explanation for this?
Thank you!

Comment: I just forgot to say "hello everyone" in the first line, And "edit" doesn't work so far:(

Comment: May be `colMeans(scaled_data) <= .Machine$double.eps`

Comment: You can check the guidelines for asking [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in case of any doubts.  But, I think the "hello ..." is not required

Comment: Thank you for all. But what I am looking for is make the result of colMeans(scaled_data) = 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a floating point issue. You can refer [floating point issue in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874867/floating-point-issue-in-r)

Simple fix is to use

```
round(colMeans(scaled_data),6)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but It is not that I am looking for. I am looking for something about options(). So after fixing, I want like this: colMeans(scaled_data)) =  0 0 0 0