# I do not understand why this test does not work properly

Tags: r

I am stuck with this:

```
t1=1.698
t2=2.457
valuest=seq(t1, t2,by=10^(-3))

valuest[2] # I get 1.699

valuest[2]==1.699  # FALSE
```

Any help?

Comment: See: `sprintf("%.20f", valuest[2])`

Comment: and try `round(valuest[2], 3) == 1.699`, `round(valuest[2], 3) == valuest[2]`

Comment: Thank you! I try `round` and it now works! But I do not understand what `sprintf` would do and why I need to round a number which would not need rounding.

Comment: Comparing floating-point numbers for equality is almost always a bad idea. It is a fertile source of bugs.

Comment: Use `all.equal(valuest[2], 1.699)`

Comment: See what you get from `sprintf("%.20f", valuest[2])` and what you get from `sprintf("%.20f", 1.699)`.

Comment: A similar question with more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874867/floating-point-issue-in-r

Comment: I can see with `sprintf` that a different approximation is used. I guess it's never too late to learn some basics about coding. As far as I understand, equality should not be tested with `==` when dealing with not integer numbers. Is that correct? Thanks a lot to everybody!